# Git Branch Merges When Working on Both

Tags: git, visual-studio, merge

I have these two branches - "Order", "Dialogue"

Order came first, and I `git checkout -b Dialogue`, i did some work on this branch, i then pushed it up to the git in the cloud.

I then checked out back to "Order", I did a little bit of work on this - I want "Dialogue" to have these updates. Do I do this?

```
# git checkout Dialogue
# git merge -m "Pulled in some updates" Order
```

Then carry on making changes on "Dialogue", once everything is going well, merge it down to "Order".

```
# git checkout "Order"
# git merge -m "Pulled in from Dialogue" Dialogue
```

Now the main concern is that I use `Visual Studio` and every time you open and close a project it modifies the `.suo` file. So when I do a merge from `Order => Dialogue` its going to say it can't because the same file and line has been modified, obviously I want to take the `Dialogue` as the ones to overwrite the `Order` modifications. I know it won't override the changes I'm doing!

Is this the way to do it? Or is there a better way?

Comment: What if you just ignore this file (yes, with .gitignore)? I'd like you to check [this project](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore#L4) - its .gitignore file is quite comprehensive, so it might take more than just .suo file. )

Comment: Is there a standard set of files to ignore, somewhere on some website that lists what should be ignored, I don't particularly want to go through myself, I don't know what isn't or is needed!

Comment: Well, I believe I have actually given the link to it. )

Comment: Sorry, trying to do too many things at once!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a .gitignore text file in the root of your repository (or in the solution folder).

inside of it, put the following line:

```
*.suo
```

OR

Just use GitHub's standard [Visual Studio .gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) and customize it as you see fit.  This will handle most of the files you shouldn't check in.

Answer (score 0):

Is the .suo file part of the project (if it got deleted would that be a problem)?  If so, then it matters.  If not, then it shouldn't be in the list of things that git tracks in the first place: the .gitignore file might be handy for this case.